# How to extract WorkItems from query in VSTS (Azure DevOps) with Python REST API?

Tags: python, rest, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the official Python REST API of Azure DevOps: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api

Thanks to the samples I have been able to retrieve information on Test Cases from ids.

How to do it from queries (WIQL)?

Here is my code so far (with modified tokens and links):

```
from vsts.vss_connection import VssConnection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication


token = "hcykwckuhe6vbnigsjs7r3ai2jefsdlkfjslkfj5mxizbtfu6k53j4ia"
team_instance = "https://tfstest.toto.com:8443/tfs/Development/"

credentials = BasicAuthentication("", token)
connection = VssConnection(base_url=team_instance, creds=credentials)


def print_work_items(work_items):
    for work_item in work_items:
        print(
            "{0} {1}: {2}".format(
                work_item.fields["System.WorkItemType"],
                work_item.id,
                work_item.fields["System.Title"],
            )
        )


WIT_CLIENT = (
    "vsts.work_item_tracking.v4_1.work_item_tracking_client.WorkItemTrackingClient"
)
wit_client = connection.get_client(WIT_CLIENT)


def get_TC_by_id(desired_ids):
    work_items = wit_client.get_work_items(ids=desired_ids, error_policy="omit")
    print_work_items(work_items)


def get_TC_from_query(query):
    # THIS FUNCTION IS NOT WORKING...
    work_items = wit_client.get_work_items(query=query, error_policy="omit")
    print_work_items(work_items)


get_TC_by_id([1035375])

get_TC_from_query(
    """\
SELECT
        [System.Id],
        [System.WorkItemType],
        [System.Title],
        [System.State],
        [System.AreaPath],
        [System.IterationPath]
FROM workitems
WHERE
        [System.TeamProject] = @project
        AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Test Case'
ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC
"""
)
```

This is the error I get

```
  File "test_TFS.py", line 35, in get_TC_from_query
    work_items = wit_client.get_work_items(query=query, error_policy="omit")
TypeError: get_work_items() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query'
```

How shall I retrieve Test Cases from a query?

In particular, I do not understand the values of the "client" such as `"vsts.work_item_tracking.v4_1.work_item_tracking_client.WorkItemTrackingClient"`

Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After posting a message (i.e. issue leading to a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-samples/pull/9)) on the Github repository for VSTS examples, I got a hint to solve my issue.

The solution is to use:

- a wiql query object with `Wiql` class
- `query_by_wiql` function
- transforming the results of the query (references with WorkItem id) to WorkItem with `get_work_item` function (or `get_work_items` to process several WorkItems in a single pass)

---

Here is my solution to this problem:

**[UPDATED FOR VERSION 5.1 and azure-devops module replacing VSTS]**

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.v5_1.work_item_tracking.models import Wiql


token = "hcykwckuhe6vbnigsjs7r3ai2jefsdlkfjslkfj5mxizbtfu6k53j4ia"
team_instance = "https://tfstest.toto.com:8443/tfs/Development/"

credentials = BasicAuthentication("", token)
connection = Connection(base_url=team_instance, creds=credentials)


def print_work_items(work_items):
    for work_item in work_items:
        print(
            "{0} {1}: {2}".format(
                work_item.fields["System.WorkItemType"],
                work_item.id,
                work_item.fields["System.Title"],
            )
        )


wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()


def get_TC_from_query(query):
    query_wiql = Wiql(query=query)
    results = wit_client.query_by_wiql(query_wiql).work_items
    # WIQL query gives a WorkItemReference => we get the corresponding WorkItem from id
    work_items = (wit_client.get_work_item(int(result.id)) for result in results)
    print_work_items(work_items)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is faster to request items in bulk. However, there is a limit to how many items you can request at once, so you need to slice the list into 200 item chunks.

This will also handle different query styles (`workitems` or `workitemLinks`)

```py
def get_TC_from_query(query):
    query_wiql = Wiql(query)
    query_result = wit_client.query_by_wiql(query_wiql)
    if query_result.query_result_type.lower() == 'workitemlink':
        items = [relation.target for relation in query_result.work_item_relations]
    elif query_result.query_result_type.lower() == 'workitem':
        items = query_result.work_items
    else:
        raise AttributeError(f"Incorrect type for {query_result.query_result_type}")

    # get_work_items can only handle 200 items per search
    size_chunks = 200
    for idx in range(0, len(items), size_chunks):
        search_items = items[idx:idx+size_chunks]
        yield from wit_client.get_work_items([x.id for x in search_items], expand='all')
```